# Code style formatting in Tibco BusinessEvents

Tags: formatting, styles, tibco, businessevents

Question: Where are the settings of code style formatting in Tibco BusinessEvents project ?

BusinessEvents is based on Eclipse but I could not find the settings of code style formatting.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't do code formatting.  No joke.